# Afterimage when scrolled in activity menu

Tags: gnome, menu, 19.10

Specs (provided via a comment):

VM Spec is 4 core 10gb ram. Host machine is i7-6700 4C8T 16 gb ram installed

---

There is a afterimage when scroll in application menu on Ubuntu 19.10 like following picture.
How I can fix it?

I using ubuntu 19.10 on virtualbox that host is windows10.

It looks like there is no problem of video card because there is nothing wrong with display in Host OS.

My desktop system is gnome(ubuntu default)

[image]

Comment: You'll need mentioning the resources allotted to the VM.

Comment: What resources I need mentioned?

Comment: Like how many CPU cores and RAM (and video RAM?) you've given the VM. Also, your host machine specs would help.

Comment: VM Spec is 4 core 10gb ram. Host machine is i7-6700 4C8T 16 gb ram installed

Comment: What packages are considered broken if it caused by broken package?